# How to solve the problem of using Clean... in P4V but calling Reconcile -n preview result and causing exclusive lock file cannot be cleaned

Tags: perforce, p4v, perforce-client-spec

As mentioned in the question, I often encounter the situation shown in the picture below:
[Problems demonstrate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdjkT.png)

I'm using the `Clean...` directive here, not the `Reconcile Offline Work...`directive
[Clean...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQ9th.png)

Comment: Are you asking what the message "can't edit exclusive file already opened" means? It means that you've told Perforce that only one client at a time can have that file opened for edit. https://community.perforce.com/s/article/3114

Comment: I mean I use "Clean..." to clean up the file, but the file is in an exclusive state, and P4V calls the Reconcile function to preview the result of Clean, resulting in the inability to properly clean the modified file.

Answer (score 2):

This bug was fixed in the server in release 2016.2:

https://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/user/relnotes.txt

```
    #1382996 (Job #74886, #86396) **
        'p4 clean' would fail to sync files when needed when they
        are exclusively opened by another client. This has been
        fixed.
```

Double check that you're on release 2016.2+ of the server; if you are, you should be at the very least be able to use `p4 clean` as a workaround (e.g. by adding it as a custom tool to P4V).

Comment: If you have a support contract with Perforce, you can report the P4V behavior to them; it seems like the sort of thing that should be an easy fix.  That aside, `+l` files are generally obnoxious and I recommend avoiding their use unless *absolutely* necessary.  :)

Comment: If I use `p4 clean` it will work correctly, but the Clean... behavior of P4V seems to call the function `p4 reconcile -n`, not `p4 clean -n`(`p4 reconcile -w -n`).

Comment: `(e.g. by adding it as a custom tool to P4V)` Yeah, that's one of the solutions I'm considering if I miss the official solution